# Is it possible to use androids print api without bothering the user with UI?

Tags: android, printing

I read many questions on how to print from android straight to printers. I guess since Android 4.4 everyone should just use androids print API.

Do print-calls to the API always involve or require user interaction (like printer dialogs)?

Is it possible to write code that prints via androids default printer without bothering the user with "print-dialogs"?

Comment: did u get any solution??

Comment: Not exactly. The original question was specifically related to Android's print API. I don't think you can bypass the UI dialogs. Our implementation (ipp-software.com) of ipp does not depend on PrintKit (Android) or javax.print (JavaSE / like CUPS4J does) and thus supports Android as well.